# How to get status code in selenium chrome web driver in python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am looking for status_code in selenium but can't find any code that suits my need. My other problem is that when I enter a domain which does not exists lets say https://gghgjeggeg.com. Selenium does not raises any eror. It's page source is like:-

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

How can I get status code(for valid domains eg:https://twiitter.com/404errpage) as well as raise error for non existing domains in Selenium or is there any other library like Selenium?

Comment: You can use Python `urllib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is not meant to be used to directly examine HTTP status codes. Selenium is used to interact with the website like a user would do. And the typical user would not open the developer tools and observe the HTTP status code but look at the page content.

I even saw pages responding with a HTTP 200 OK delivering a "resource not found" message to the user.

Even the Selenium developers addressed this:

> The browser will always represent the HTTP status code, imagine for example a 404 or a 500 error page. A simple way to “fail fast” when you encounter one of these error pages is to check the page title or content of a reliable point (e.g. the `<h1>` tag) after every page load.

Source: [selenium.dev / Worst practices / HTTP response codes](https://selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/http_response_codes/)

If you insist using Selenium you're better off finding the first `h1` element and looking for the typical Chrome 404 signature:

```
h1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1')
if h1.text == u"This site can’t be reached":
    print("Not found")
```

Although, if you want to crawl websites, you might even use urllib, like Tek Nath suggested in the comments:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.request
import urllib.error

try:
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.safasdfsadfsadfdsf.org/') as f:
        print(f.read())
        print(f.status)
        print(f.getheader("content-length"))
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print(e.reason)
```

Since the domain is not existing, the code will run into the exception handler branch.

See the Python documentation for details and more examples:

- [`urllib` API](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html)
- [`HTTPResponse` object interface](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.client.html#httpresponse-objects)

You might then want to use a DOM parser to process the HTML markup to a DOM tree for easier processing. Though this is beyond this question - get started here:

- [`xml.dom`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=dom) (Python documentation)
- ["Python: Is there a built in package to parse html into dom"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782097/python-is-there-a-built-in-package-to-parse-html-into-dom) (Stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks. I have one more solution to use selenium-wire library

Comment: @Mr.Explorerexplorer, great, consider providing an answer yourself (yes, that is possible and encouraged) and provide a small example and references.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox or Chrome u can use addons for this. 
We save status code in response cookies and read this cookie on selenium side.

U can read more about browser extensions here:

Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials

NOTE: (Not certificated addons works only with Firefox Dev version, if u want use standard Firefox u must certificate your extension on firefox site.)

**Chrome version**

```js
//your_js_file_with_extension.js

var targetPage = "*://*/*";

function setStatusCodeDiv(e) {
    chrome.cookies.set({
        url: e.url,
        name: 'status-code',
        value: `${e.statusCode}`
    });
}

chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  setStatusCodeDiv,
  {urls: [targetPage], types: ["main_frame"]}
);
```

manifest:

```
{
  "description": "Save http status code in site cookies",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "StatusCodeInCookies",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest", "*://*/*", "cookies"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "your_js_file_with_extension.js" ]
  }
}
```

**Firefox version** is almost the same.

```js
//your_js_file_with_extension.js

var targetPage = "*://*/*";

function setStatusCodeDiv(e) {
  browser.cookies.set({
    url: e.url,
    name: 'status-code',
    value: `${e.statusCode}`
  });
}

browser.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  setStatusCodeDiv,
  {urls: [targetPage], types: ["main_frame"]}
);
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "description": "Save http status code in site cookies",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "StatusCodeInCookies",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest", "*://*/*", "cookies"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "your_js_file_with_extension.js" ]
  },

  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "some_id"
    }
  }
}
```

Next u must build this extensions:

For Chrome u must create *.pem and *.crx files (powershell script):

```
start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  -ArgumentList "--pack-extension=C:\Path\to\your\js\and\manifest"
```

Firefox (We need only zip file):

```
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory('C:\Path\to\your\js\and\manifest', 'destination\folder')
```

**Selenium** steps

Ok, when we have extension we can add this to our selenium app.
I write our version in C# but i think is easy to rewrite this to other languages (Here u can find Python ver: [Using Extensions with Selenium (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511384/using-extensions-with-selenium-python)).

Load extension with Chrome drive:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddExtension(Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory,@"Selenium\BrowsersExtensions\Compiled\YOUR_CHROME_EXTENSION.crx"));
var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options);
```

Load with Firefox (U must use profile):

```
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();       
profile.AddExtension(Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory,@"Selenium\BrowsersExtensions\Compiled\YOUR_FIREFOX_EXTENSION.zip"));
var options = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = profile
};
var firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options);
```

Ok we almost done, now we need read status code from cookies, this should looks something like:

```
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl('your_url');
if (webDriver.Manage() is IOptions options 
    && options.Cookies.GetCookieNamed("status-code") is Cookie cookie
    && int.TryParse(cookie.Value, out var statusCode))
{
    //we delete cookies after we read status code but this is not necessary
    options.Cookies.DeleteCookieNamed("status-code");
    return statusCode;
}
logger.Warn($"Can't get http status code from {webDriver.Url}");
return 500;
```

And this is all. I have not seen anywhere answer like this. Hope I helped.